# How can I get the image to properly wrap around the text using Bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to get an image to position to the left of the text which will then wrap similar to the 1st image I have attached [layout I am trying to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uNpJ.png)

For some reason the image stays in the same column as the text underneath it, or it appears like the 2nd image that I have attached.
 [the way it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxHTK.png) I am learning bootstrap 4 so some positioning isn't working correctly on some elements. Sorry for not placing the code correctly I ctl+k but it didn't work.

Can someone help solve this issue for me?

```
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" class="img-responsive float-left mr-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
          ut labore et dolore
          magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
          ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
          nulla
          pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
          anim id est
          laborum. be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters
          to this
          principle of
          selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid
          worse
          pains."</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <p>
          "On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and
          demoralized by
          the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and
          trouble that
          are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of
          will, which is
          the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy
          to
          distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our
          being able
          to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain
          circumstances
          and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that
          pleasures have to
          be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this
          principle of
          selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid
          worse
          pains."
        </p>
        <p>
          3rd paragraph here. Get to talking
        </p>
      </div>


</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look to your large column, it is col-lg-2 of a total of 12, than you have your first paragraph col-lg-10, which combines image and text 12, which means the total width of your page, now the one below is only 10, so it'll display around 83.33% of your page, try to change that for col-lg-12, so it will match the img+first paragraph. [Take a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk7s4.png)

this is simple how you use it...

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" class="img-responsive float-left mr-3">
</div>

<div class="col-lg-10">
        <p>Paragraph1</p>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-10">
        <p>Paragraph2</p>
</div>
```